# How do I access JSON elements and put the contents into lists?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON list of objects like this:

```json
"server-1": {
    "username": "admin542",
    "on_break": false,
    "scheduling_type": 1,
    "schedule": {
      "Monday": [
        "11:00"
      ],
      "Tuesday": [
        "12:00",
        "13:00"
      ],
    },
    "com_type": 2
  },
  "server-2": {
    "username": "admin543",
    "on_break": false,
    "scheduling_type": 2,
    "schedule": {
      "Monday": [
        "10:00"
      ],
      "Wednesday": [
        "13:00",
        "14:00"
      ]
    },
    "com_type": 2
  },
```

**I want to access the schedule for a specific server and put it into lists.** Let's say I want to access the schedule for **server-2.** How can I access it and put it in a list like this?

```py
schedule_days = ["Monday", "Wednesday"]
schedule_times = [["10:00"], ["13:00", "14:00"]]
```

I tried with:

```py
import json

with open("systemfile.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

schedule_days = []
schedule_days.append(data[str("server-2")]["schedule"])

### Which gave me

[{'Monday': ['11:00'], 'Wednesday': ['13:00', '14:00']}]
```

Is there any way I can access that to make a list like the example above? Or what would you do?

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data['server-2']['schedule']` is the sub-dictionary you want to access.  You can use the `.keys()` method of this dictionary to get the keys, and the `.values()` method to get the values.

```
schedule_days = list(data['server-2']['schedule'].keys())
schedule_times = list(data['server-2']['schedule'].values())
```